# Sharing data between two vue files using variable defined in main js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two separate vue files:- for example `1.vue` and `2.vue` and a main js file.

I have a variable `xyz` under window.App data: method in main.js

I want to access this variable as a share data variable how will I use it in my both the vue files. for example `1.vue` will put some data under this variable and `2.vue` will access this data.

Comment: 1.vue will emit an event, main will update the value, and 2.vue will receive it as a prop. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Comment: How it will work for global data:- I mean, in main.js  `window.App = new Vue({
 
 el: '#app',
 data: {
    xyz: {}
   },`    and 1.vue put data in xyz and 2.vue use it .. I dont understand how to create a method in 1.vue to access this variable

Comment: Components should not access variables that are not their own. Just because `App` is global does not mean its `data` should be treated as global. It should not. Encapsulation is important. Components should not depend on things that are external to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

If you need to pass datas from a component to another. You should use props in the child component and v-bind or : in the parent.

Parent Vue :

```
<child-component :datas="array"></child-component>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    array: [1,2,3]
  })
</script>
```

Child Vue:

```
<div v-for="item in array"></div>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    array: Array // Array is the typeof (can be Object, Array or String)
  }
</script>
```

PS : It was a bit hard for me to make it works.

Edit : Or maybe you can use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) class to create and update the variable

Comment: How it will work for global data:- I mean, in main.js  `window.App = new Vue({
 
 el: '#app',
 data: {
    xyz: {}
   },`    and 1.vue put data in xyz and 2.vue use it .. I dont understand how to create a method in 1.vue to access this variable

Comment: I think it should work this way. That's how I do with Vue Router.
Can't you acces xyz in other component ?
Try to type "window.app.data.xyz" in the console.
Otherwise, you can attach your data to the Global Scope. To the window by example (if datas is not security sensitive)

Comment: Is it possible to create method in 1.vue like this `getdata: function(app){window.App.xyz = app;
        '2.vue';
}`

Comment: Probably, but it's a bit ugly, I would try to do it with Vue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two recommended ways to pass data between components (eg 1.vue and 2.vue)

1. Using props and events. You have xyz defined in your root instance data. When using the component declared in 1.vue, pass the value as a prop (property) and add this as a value as a prop in 1.vue. When the value changes in 1.vue, trigger an event which updates the value in the root instance, so that 2.vue can also see this value through a prop.
2. Use [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex). Vuex creates a shared state that all components can see via a store. You update the value through mutations and actions, and other components will automatically react to these changes using a computation.